# Limitations on recipients in a CRL parameter?

Tags: docusignapi

I am in the middle of building this custom button and assigned the recipients and routing like so:

```
//Custom Recipient List 
var CRL='Email~test1@test.com;FirstName~Test1;LastName~Test1;Role~A;RoutingOrder~1,Email~test2@test.com;FirstName~Test2;LastName~Test2;Role~B;RoutingOrder~2,Email~test3@test.com;FirstName~Test3;LastName~Test3;Role~C;RoutingOrder~3,Email~jiraadmins@test.com;FirstName~Jira;LastName~Admins;Role~D;RoutingOrder~4,Email~test1@triadretail.com;FirstName~Test1;LastName~Test1;Role~E;RoutingOrder~5,Email~jiraadmins@test.com;FirstName~Jira;LastName~Admins;Role~F;RoutingOrder~5,Email~test2@test.com;FirstName~Test2;LastName~Test2;Role~G;RoutingOrder~5,Email~test3@test.com;FirstName~Test3;LastName~Test3;Role~H;RoutingOrder~5';

//Custom Contact Role Map 
var CCRM='A~Signer 1;B~Signer 2;C~Carbon Copy;D~Signer 3;E~Carbon Copy;F~Carbon Copy;G~Carbon Copy;H~Carbon Copy'; 

//Custom Contact Map 
var CCTM='A~Signer;B~Signer;C~Carbon Copy;D~Signer;E~Carbon Copy;F~Carbon Copy;G~Carbon Copy;H~Carbon Copy';
```

I did check the envelope settings in Salesforce, and I have in the list Signer 1, Signer 2, Signer 3, etc. until I get to Signer 9.

The odd thing is that when I click my custom button, it's only listing the first four recipients and doesn't acknowledge the last 4.  Is there something that I may be missing or does it have a limit on how many recipients it shows?

Thanks!

Rachel

Comment: I know there's a 1000 character limit on the CRL but you're barely above 600 so that's not it.  I noticed that recipients 5, 6, 7, and 8 all share routingOrder = 5, have you tried testing with sequential order them?  Does more than 4 of them show then?

Comment: I just tried fixing the routing order and it's still not showing the other four recipients?  Does it have anything to do with that they are a carbon copy role?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely a combination of two things:

- The **Recipient Role Settings** that have been specified on the **DocuSign Admin** >> **Envelopes** page.
- Incorrect contents/values in the **CCRM** parameter.

In Salesforce, navigate to the **DocuSign Admin** tab, and then to the "**Envelopes**" page...you'll see a section like this that specifies Recipient Role Names:

[image: Role Names]

The Role Names there need to match up with those that you specify in the CCRM parameter. It's best to use a generic naming convention like "Recipient1, Recipient2,..." etc.

Then, when setting the **CCRM** parameter in the custom button script, map each "Role" value from your **CRL** parameter to a value from the aforementioned "Role Names" list:

```
//Custom Contact Role Map 
var CCRM='A~Recipient1;B~Recipient2;C~Recipient3;D~Recipient4;E~Recipient5;F~Recipient6;G~Recipient7;H~Recipient8';
```

As long as the values you're specifying in the **CCRM** parameter correspond to values that exist in the **DocuSign Admin >> Envelopes >> Role Names** list, the resulting envelope should contain all 8 recipients, as shown here:

[image: DS Recipients]

Answer (score 1):

I did the answer to my issue.  For the Carbon Copy recipients, I needed to separate them out.  So CC 1, CC 2, CC 3, and so on and so forth.  Once I did that, everything was working peachy.

Thanks to everyone who looked into this and helped out!